# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__' when running django-maintenancemode

Tags: python, django

I am running into this error when trying to run this middleware in django. https://github.com/shanx/django-maintenancemode

It is returning a

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'.
```

Is there something i am doing wrong? I am trying to test his out in my localhost environment within a virtualenv. I have placed the middleware into the settings file and this error is returned regardless of whether i have the mode set to true or false. I have placed a 503.html template within my templates folder which i want it to serve.

## Traceback

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 51, in load_middleware
    mod = import_module(mw_module)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django_maintenancemode-0.9.3-py2.7.egg\maintenancemode\middleware.py", line 6, in <module>
    defaults.__all__.append('handler503')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
[11/Jul/2013 14:57:57] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python27\Lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 72, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 236, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 51, in load_middleware
    mod = import_module(mw_module)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django\utils\importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\Deep.C\.virtualenvs\dcwebdev\lib\site-packages\django_maintenancemode-0.9.3-py2.7.egg\maintenancemode\middleware.py", line 6, in <module>
    defaults.__all__.append('handler503')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__all__'
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback. They indicate where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using version 0.9.3 which is old and unsupported and broken against recent releases of Django. Upgrade to 0.10 and you'll get something which works.

([The critical line](https://github.com/shanx/django-maintenancemode/blob/master/maintenancemode/middleware.py#L16) now modifies [the correct object](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/conf/urls/__init__.py#L8); [django.conf.urls.default no longer has `__all__` defined](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/conf/urls/defaults.py))